# Is almost sure convergence of the entries implies almost sure convergence of the vector?

Tags: probability, random-matrices, strong-convergence

Say I have two sequences $\boldsymbol{X}_n\in\mathbb{R}^6$ and $\boldsymbol{Y}_n\in\mathbb{R}^8$, such that
$$\boldsymbol{X}_n\rightarrow_{\text{almost surely}}\boldsymbol{X},$$
and
$$\boldsymbol{Y}_n\rightarrow_{\text{almost surely}}\boldsymbol{Y}.$$
Does this imply that

$$(\boldsymbol{X}_n,\boldsymbol{Y}_n)\rightarrow_{\text{almost surely}}(\boldsymbol{X},\boldsymbol{Y})$$
?

Comment: Yes (if the probability space is in common). In general if $A,B$ are events with $P(A)=1=P(B)$ then also $P(A\cap B)=1$ because $P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)=1+1-1=1$. Moreover if $a_n\to a$ and $b_n\to b$ then $(a_n,b_n)\to(a,b)$.

Comment: @drhab If I may, I have a follow-up question: If I have $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Pr(|X_n-Y_n|=0)=1$, and I know that $Y_n\rightarrow Y$ almost surely, can I deduce that $X_n\rightarrow Y$ almost surely?

Comment: The answer on that is negative. If it would be true then - taking $Y_n=Y=0$ for every $n$ - we would arrive at the **false** implication that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Pr(|X_n|=0)=1\implies X_n\to0\text{ a.s.}$

Comment: Why is this false? Doesn't this mean by definition that $X_n$ converges to zero almost surely? Doesn't $\Pr(|X_n|=0)=1$  implies that $\Pr(X_n=0)=1$?

Comment: $\Pr(|X_n|=0)=1$ does indeed imply that $P(X_n=0)=1$ but that is not the point. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Pr(|X_n|=0)=1$ does not imply that $P(\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n=0)=1$ (i.e. we do not have $X_n\to0$ a.s.). For instance working on $\Omega=(0,1]$ with uniform distribution let the $X_n$ be characteristic functions of the intervals $(0,\frac12],(\frac12,1],(0,\frac13],(\frac13,\frac23],(\frac23,1],(0,\frac14],\dots$. The intervals get smaller and smaller so that $P(|X_n|=0)$ converges to $1$. But for every $\omega\in(0,1]$ sequence $X_n(\omega)$ is not convergent.

Comment: Thanks. So if I would have $\Pr(\lim |X_n - Y_n|=0)=1)$ and $Y_n\rightarrow Y$ almost surely, this would be suffice to deduce that $X_n\rightarrow Y$ almost surely?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.